# Are printer drivers technically possible?

Tags: connection-issues, usb-drivers, usb-peripherals, printing, peripherals

It seems that printer manufacturers like Canon provide a printing app for Android devices, from which you can print documents and images stored on your Android device, but not printer drivers. So you cannot just print from any app, in the way that you can print from any program on a computer with printer drivers installed.

Is there a technical reason why there are no regular printer drivers for Android devices? Or is it just a choice made by manufacturers?

Comment: Is [HP Print Service Plugin](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hp.android.printservice) considered as a "printer driver" in your context? That aside, printing is only available [natively since Android 4.4 KitKat](https://developer.android.com/training/printing) and needs to be implemented by each individual app.

Comment: @AndrewT. That indeed seems to have regular printer driver functionality. They even call it a printer driver. And if an app doesn't support the "print" option, you can use "share", which is a logical way of doing this generically on Android, I guess. I wonder why not every printer manufacturer followed HP's example on this.